# failing to populate bootsrap row with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript

i have a bootstrap row that  has to contain tow rows to encapsulate two array values using angular js . I want to loop through an array of friends using ng-repeat and fill the rows accordingly but am failing any help? my code is here

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="height:2240px;">
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="friend in fullUser.friends">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:40px;">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="user_profile.php" class="black2">                          
                        <span>                              
                            <table>                                 
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img ng-src="{{friend.avatar}}" class="img-circle" style="width:100px;height:100px"  alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span style="margin-bottom:0px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{friend.name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Friend</span>
                                        <hr style="margin-bottom:-15px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;height:8px;width:248px;"></hr>
                                        &nbsp;<span style="margin-top:-10px;font-size:25px;margin-left:223px;color:#BD2532;" class="icon icon-caret-down"></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                        </span>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6" ng-if="$index % 2 === 0" > 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="user_profile.php" class="black2">
                        <span>                              
                            <table>                                 
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img ng-src="{{friend.avatar}}" class="img-circle" style="width:100px;height:100px"  alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span style="margin-bottom:0px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{friend.name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Friend</span>
                                        <hr style="margin-bottom:-15px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;height:8px;width:248px;"></hr>
                                        &nbsp;<span style="margin-top:-10px;font-size:25px;margin-left:223px;color:#BD2532;" class="icon icon-caret-down"></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>


</div>
```

Comment: I finally figured it out Using javascript logic